# Type coincidence using malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

i've got a question about the malloc function used as in the following example:

```
char *block = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
```

Why does the assignment work when the type on the left is the content(*) of a pointer and the type on the right is a pointer?

Comment: It is a pointer to pointer assignment.  The _type_ on the left is is not the content of the pointer, the type on the left is a pointer - in this case a pointer to `char`.  IAC, I recommend `char *block = malloc(sizeof *block * 1024);`

Comment: It is an initialisation, which *more or less* mimics the syntax of an assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, in an expression, `*x` refers to the thing `x` points to. In an expression, `*` is an operator that means to use the object that is pointed to.

In a declaration, `*` is not an operator. In a declaration, you explain what type you want a thing to be by “showing” what an expression will look like and say what type you want that expression to be. So, in `char *block`, we are saying “we want the expression `*block` to be a `char`.” From this, the compiler deduces that `block` must be a pointer to a `char`.

Then, in the full declaration `char *block = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));`, we are saying “Declare `block` to be a pointer to `char` and then initialize `block` to the result of `malloc`.”. We are initializing `block`, not `*block`.

In other words, an assignment expression assigns the value on the right to the object on the left. A declaration assigns the value on the right as the initial value of the thing declared on the left. Because of the special syntax of declarations, the thing declared on the left is just the identifier inside it, not the entire left side interpreted as an expression.